# How should the GM rule on the inquisitor spell judgment light?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature

An [inquisitor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor) with an active purity [judgment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor#TOC-Judgment-Su-) casts the 4th-level inquisitor spell [*judgment light*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/j/judgment-light). In a 30-ft. radius burst centered on the caster the following instantaneous effect occurs:

> #### Original
>
> White light erupts from the caster, allowing each ally within the burst to attempt a saving throw against a single effect that allows a saving throw with a +2 sacred bonus on the roll.

That's... not very playable. What this means was the subject of a very short [thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ozeq?Judgement-Light-Spell) on Paizo's *Pathfinder RPG* forums in Oct. 2012, but that thread was met mostly with silence.

I suspect it was supposed to have an effect something like this...

> #### Revision
>
> Each ally within the burst makes another saving throw against 1 ongoing effect the ally picks that allowed an saving throw initially. The ally gains a +2 sacred bonus on this saving throw. Success on this additional saving throw means the ally is now affected by the picked effect as if the ally had succeeded on the initial saving throw.

...But I'd like confirmation.

#### Is the revision true to the original's spirit? If not, what's an alternative?

Also, when an inquistor with an active justice judgment casts the 4th-level inquisitor spell *judgment light*, there occurs in a 30-ft. radius burst centered on the caster the following instantaneous effect:

> Blue light erupts from the caster, revealing hidden and invisible creatures to all. The light outlines such creatures for 1 round per caster level, imposing a −20 penalty on Stealth checks on those creatures.

The other effects of the spell judgment light (besides destruction and healing) are all parallel, describing the light color first and, in the same sentence, the mechanics.

#### Does this effect reveal hidden and invisible creatures *or* does the effect only cause hidden and invisible creatures to suffer the −20 penalty to their Stealth skill checks?

That is, does the spell's effect reveal hidden and invisible creatures in a manner similar to the spell [*invisibility purge*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility-purge) *and* limn hidden and invisible creatures, making those creatures suffer a −20 penalty to their Stealth skill checks, ***or*** just limn the hidden and invisible creatures?

Comment: More than invisible purge, I would compare the effect with the secondary effect of  [glitterdust](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glitterdust). Also, maybe you should split the question into two different questions.

Comment: @MACN The *glitterdust* parallel *is* interesting. I considered splitting this into 2 questions, but I couldn't imagine someone experienced in adjudicating the spell having an opinion on one one part yet not on the other. I'll keep the question contained unless demand is overwhelming.

Answer (score 3):

## Purity Judgement

I read the effect as-written as:

> All allies within 30 feet choose an ongoing effect which is affecting them; they may attempt to save (with a +2 sacred bonus) against that effect (even if it normally does not allow a second save), using the effect's original save DC. Success either counts as a success towards removing the effect (for poisons and such) or removes the effect; failure has no ill effects (eg., if you're poisoned and fail this save, you don't take the poison's damage).

The revision in your question is slightly more powerful, if only because it raises the possibility that a dead character (eg., who has failed a save against the Poison option of Prismatic Spray) could make a save and actually not have died.

## Justice Judgement

I think that the effect is pretty plain: for one round per caster level, all creatures within 30 feet of the caster, which are either affected by Invisibility or actively using Stealth, are limned; this causes them to suffer a -20 penalty to their Stealth checks. This nicely removes the +20 bonus that immobile, invisible creatures get to their Stealth. So, a creature can still try to hide, but they're going to have a hard time of it. I don't see an Invisibility Purge in there, but a -20 to Stealth is only very slightly different.